# Bizarre behavior in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, debug-symbols

I'm experiencing a very strange bug in my code.

I use a variable `m_requestedStructures` in my program, and the debugger is accessing the wrong address when inspecting it. For example, I have in the code:

```
qDebug() << "requested: " << m_requestedStructures << " " << &m_requestedStructures
```

and I set a breakpoint here. When the breakpoint is reached, I compare the printed value and address of `m_requestedStructures` with those that gdb is accessing:

```
requested:  0   0xfce640 
Breakpoint 1
157         qDebug() << "requested: " << m_requestedStructures << " " << &m_requestedStructures;
(gdb) p m_requestedStructures
$5 = -1167616
(gdb) p &m_requestedStructures
$6 = (int *) 0xfce644
(gdb)
```

As can be seen, both the value and the address differ.

Another symptom I'm seeing is that I had a function, `QueueManager::checkPopulation_()` which I removed quite a while ago, but gdb still tries to tab-complete it, and if I set a breakpoint on it, it will break at the point where the function *used* to be.

It appears to me that the symbols aren't read correctly. I've tried rebuilding from a clean directory, but the problem persists. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I just tried setting a breakpoint on a new function I've added. The function `QueueManager::run()` appears in gdb's tab complete, but when I try to set the breakpoint, I get

```
the class GlobalSearch::QueueManager does not have any method named run
```

Also, inspecting other variables, both locally scoped and members of QueueManager, seems to work fine.

Here is the compiler/linker output. The file containing the class is `queuemanager.cpp`, which is part of a static library `libglobalsearch.a`, which is used in a dynamic library `xtalopt.so`:

```
$ make VERBOSE=1 xtalopt
/usr/bin/cmake -H/git/xtalopt-public -B/git/xtalopt-public/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 xtalopt
make[1]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -H/git/xtalopt-public -B/git/xtalopt-public/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles 63
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 src/xtalopt/CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/all
make[2]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make -f src/spglib/CMakeFiles/spglib.dir/build.make src/spglib/CMakeFiles/spglib.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /git/xtalopt-public /git/xtalopt-public/src/spglib /git/xtalopt-public/build /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/spglib /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/spglib/CMakeFiles/spglib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make -f src/spglib/CMakeFiles/spglib.dir/build.make src/spglib/CMakeFiles/spglib.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `src/spglib/CMakeFiles/spglib.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles  18 19 20 21 22 23
[  9%] Built target spglib
make -f src/libssh/CMakeFiles/ssh_static.dir/build.make src/libssh/CMakeFiles/ssh_static.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /git/xtalopt-public /git/xtalopt-public/src/libssh /git/xtalopt-public/build /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/libssh /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/libssh/CMakeFiles/ssh_static.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make -f src/libssh/CMakeFiles/ssh_static.dir/build.make src/libssh/CMakeFiles/ssh_static.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `src/libssh/CMakeFiles/ssh_static.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles  26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
[ 33%] Built target ssh_static
make -f src/globalsearch/CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/build.make src/globalsearch/CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /git/xtalopt-public /git/xtalopt-public/src/globalsearch /git/xtalopt-public/build /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/globalsearch /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/globalsearch/CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make -f src/globalsearch/CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/build.make src/globalsearch/CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles 
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/globalsearch/CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/queuemanager.cpp.o
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/globalsearch && /usr/bin/c++   -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SHARED -D_HAVE_EXECINFO_H_ -DQT_DEBUG -fPIC -g -I/usr/include/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/eigen2 -I/git/xtalopt-public/build -I/usr/include/openbabel-2.0 -I/git/xtalopt-public/src   -o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/queuemanager.cpp.o -c /git/xtalopt-public/src/globalsearch/queuemanager.cpp
Linking CXX static library libglobalsearch.a
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/globalsearch && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/globalsearch && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar cr libglobalsearch.a  CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/optbase.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/queuemanager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/structure.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/tracker.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/optimizer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/bt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/sshconnection.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/sshmanager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/random.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/ui/abstractdialog.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/ui/abstracttab.cpp.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_optbase.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_queuemanager.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_structure.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_tracker.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_optimizer.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_bt.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_sshconnection.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_sshmanager.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/moc_random.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/ui/moc_abstractdialog.cxx.o CMakeFiles/globalsearch.dir/ui/moc_abstracttab.cxx.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libglobalsearch.a
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
[ 55%] Built target globalsearch
make -f src/xtalopt/CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/build.make src/xtalopt/CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /git/xtalopt-public /git/xtalopt-public/src/xtalopt /git/xtalopt-public/build /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/xtalopt /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/xtalopt/CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
make -f src/xtalopt/CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/build.make src/xtalopt/CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
Linking CXX shared library xtalopt.so
cd /git/xtalopt-public/build/src/xtalopt && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC  -fPIC -g  -shared -Wl,-soname,xtalopt.so -o xtalopt.so CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/extension.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/xtalopt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/genetic.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/structures/xtal.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/xtaloptoptimizer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/vasp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/gulp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/pwscf.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/castep.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/testing/xtalopttest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/dialog.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_init.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_edit.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_opt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_sys.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_progress.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_plot.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/tab_log.cpp.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/moc_extension.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/moc_xtalopt.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/moc_genetic.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/structures/moc_xtal.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/moc_xtaloptoptimizer.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/moc_vasp.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/moc_gulp.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/moc_pwscf.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/optimizers/moc_castep.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/testing/moc_xtalopttest.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_dialog.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_init.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_edit.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_opt.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_sys.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_progress.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_plot.cxx.o CMakeFiles/xtalopt.dir/ui/moc_tab_log.cxx.o -lavogadro ../globalsearch/libglobalsearch.a ../spglib/libspglib.a -lQtOpenGL -lGLU -lGL -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext -lopenbabel -lQtGui -lQtCore ../libssh/libssh_static.a -lnsl -lresolv -lrt -lz -lssl -lcrypto 
make[3]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles  45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72
[100%] Built target xtalopt
make[2]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /git/xtalopt-public/build/CMakeFiles 0
make[1]: Leaving directory `/git/xtalopt-public/build'
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're not debugging an old binary?  That might happen if you tried something like `gdb program` instead of `gdb ./program` if `program` happens to be in your `PATH`.

Comment: What options are you compiling and linking with?  And what compiler/gdb versions?

Comment: The binary is the most recent. If I make changes to the code, the executable behaves appropriately, and new symbols I've added since removing <code>checkPopulation_<\code> appear in gdb's tab-completion. However, I just tried to set a break point on a new function, <code>QueueManager::run()</code>, and gdb complains (see edit).

Comment: You don't have any compiler optimizations turned on do you?

Comment: gdb version 7.2, gcc version 4.5.2

Comment: Have you tried disabling optimizations, cleaning out ALL old object files and binaries, and rebuilding from scratch?

Comment: @Adam, Yes, I've deleting everything in my build directory as well as the installed binary and rebuilt from scratch. The problem still persists. I've checked that there no other binary in the path as well.

Comment: @Michael I've added the relevant compiler output to the post.

Comment: Are you perhaps corrupting your stack somewhere? Did you run your executable with valgrind?

Comment: Tried to do a complete rebuild? Maybe some objects were compiled against old headers, which creates very funny bugs :D

Comment: Are you aware that you compile *queuemanager.cpp* into *queuemanager.cpp.o*, but link in both *queuemanager.cpp.o* and *moc_queuemanager.cxx.o* into *libglobalsearch.a* without recompiling *moc_queuemanager.cxx.o*?

Comment: ***OTHER THOUGHTS:*** Are you using ccache?  Have you tried disabling it?  *(setenv CCACHE_DISABLE "true")* (http://linux.die.net/man/1/ccache)  Have you tried using *nm --demangle* on your various object (.o), library (lib*.a), and executable programs to verify where QueueManager::run() exists?  Have you listed your files in *gdb* to insure you are running gdb against the files that you think you are?

Comment: One more silly thought:  Is everything compiled -fPIC?  ('Cause otherwise you might see some really weird problems...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to figure this out! Here's how:

In gdb, I printed all the shared libraries in memory with `info shared`. I copied this to a text file `shared.txt` and extracted the library names with:

```
cat shared.txt | grep -v \*|grep -v quit---|grep -v Syms\ Read|grep -v \(gdb\)|awk '{print $4}'>libs
```

From there, I checked the symbols in each library with:

```
for i in `cat libs|xargs`;do nm --demangle $i|grep checkPopulation; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo \($i\); fi;done
```

Which prints all symbols containing "checkPopulation" followed by the name of the library that contains each. My output:

```
000adb18 T GlobalSearch::QueueManager::checkPopulation()
000adb8a T GlobalSearch::QueueManager::checkPopulation_()
(/usr/lib/avogadro/1_1/contrib/randomdock.so)
000db682 T GlobalSearch::QueueManager::checkPopulation()
(/usr/lib/avogadro/1_1/contrib/xtalopt.so)
```

So this "phantom" `checkPopulation_` symbol is coming from randomdock.so, which was built a long time ago against an older version of the static `libglobalsearch.a`, which contains the now removed `GlobalSearch::QueueManager::checkPopulation_()`. Removing randomdock.so causes everything to behave as it should.

Thanks for all the suggestions -- I certainly learned a few new gdb tricks while tracking this down. There's also a lesson here about breaking API, too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI:

**Grep** has a **-e** switch, so you can handle multiple expressions at once.  E.g:

```
grep -v -e \* -e quit--- -e Syms\ Read -e \(gdb\) | awk '{print $4}' > libs
```

**nm** has a **-A** switch (print filename).  E.g:

```
cat libs | xargs nm -A --demangle | grep checkPopulation
```

Comment: Awesome -- thanks for the tips, especially grep -e. That will come in quite handy!